# How do I categorize items in a list?

Tags: list, if-statement, random, categories

```
dataset = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Grape', 'Pineapple',
           'Lettuce', 'Cabbage', 'Spinach', 'Carrot', 'Cauliflower']
ran = random.choice(dataset)
fruit = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Grape', 'Pineapple']
vegetable = ['Lettuce', 'Cabbage', 'Spinach', 'Carrot', 'Cauliflower']

if ran == vegetable:
    print('HINT: It is a vegetable!')

 else:
    print('HINT: It is a fruit!')
```

First I categorized items in a list but when I run my code it would only say the else statement.

Answer (score 1):

You have to check if it is **in** the list, an example:

```
import random

dataset = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Grape', 'Pineapple',
    'Lettuce', 'Cabbage', 'Spinach', 'Carrot', 'Cauliflower']
ran = random.choice(dataset)
fruit = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Grape', 'Pineapple']
vegetable = ['Lettuce', 'Cabbage', 'Spinach', 'Carrot', 'Cauliflower']

print(ran) // To verify the item

if ran in fruit:
    print("Fruit")
elif ran in vegetable:
    print("Vegetable")
else:
    print("Unknown")
```

Answer (score 0):

I think its because your asking if the random element, is equal to the entire "Vegetable" array, and in this case it is not, so it will return false.

Do a for loop where you loop over each element of the vegetable array (Or use an inbuilt function of a library to check if the ran elemet is contained in the vegetable array), and check the element againsed your ran variable, then if it is equal, you can print('Hint: it is a vegetable') and break out of the loop, if its not, your else statement will trigger and run: print('HINT: It is a fruit!')
:)

The only case it should return "Vegetables, (in the provided information) is if ran = ['Apple', 'Banana', 'Mango', 'Grape', 'Pineapple',
'Lettuce', 'Cabbage', 'Spinach', 'Carrot', 'Cauliflower']
(The vegetable array/dataset)